# How draw a circle in Lua?

Tags: math, lua, geometry

How can draw a circle by drawing point?

```
local x, y = 0, 0
for i = 1, 360 do
    drawPoint( (x*i), (y*i) )
end
```

I'm bad at math.

```
local x, y = 0, 0
for i = 1, 360 do
    drawPoint( math.cos(i)*(10)+x, math.sin(i)*(10)+y )
end
```

Ok I did it; But I have some questions:

1. How do I know the appropriate number place number 40 in the a loop?
2. How do I know width, and radius? Which represents the number 10 in the loop.

Comment: you need sin and cos, or better yet, implement Bresenham's algorithm.

Comment: A simple example please? : (

Comment: That would basically entail writing your code for you.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say `x` and `y` is your centre co-ordinate and `r` is the radius. Now:

```
local x, y, r = 0, 0, 1
for i = 1, 360 do
  local angle = i * math.pi / 180
  local ptx, pty = x + r * math.cos( angle ), y + r * math.sin( angle )
  drawPoint( ptx, pty )
end
```

Comment: Thank you; But I do not want a full circle I want her like this: http://i.imgur.com/jqsDduB.png

Comment: @user3499641 1. That is not a circle. 2. You can take the idea from my code above and modify it accordingly.